# checking list items in c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-core

I have a list which i use to check for already generated questions for a quiz game. The problem is that even after checking for the item, it seem that it has no effect on the app.

```
    public List<int> qList = new List<int>(26);
    
    and a qnum check
    Random r = new Random();
    int qnum = r.Next(1, 25);
    
    
    if (qList.Contains(qnum)) { wasChosen = true; }
    else
    {
    if (wasChosen == false){
"some not important things"
 qList.Add(qnum);

}
```

The goal here is to have random chosen "questions", not duplicated. Idk is that the way it should be done.
Github repo: https://github.com/ykostov/driving-flyers/tree/main/driving5 .

Comment: Where is `wasChosen` defined? If it is set to `true` once, where will it be set back to `false`? We need to see more code in order to debug this. Instead of randomizing from 1 to 25 always, remove the question from the question list and put it into the used list.

Comment: I gave the link for the github repository for the full code. Sorry i forgot to tell, the code is in Form1.cs

Comment: Phew. I don't want to read 500 lines of code. Don't put your data into the code. Use a text file, JSON file or a database.

Comment: Once `wasChosen` is set to `true`, it will remain `true` for all times. You have one `wasChosen` variable but 25 questions. How is this single variable supposed to store the state of 25 questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a logical flaw.

```
if (qList.Contains(qnum)) { wasChosen = true; }
            else
            {
                if (wasChosen == false)
                {
```

Once the `wasChosen` is set to true it is never set to false as your code is missing an assignment after adding the item to the list. Also not sure where you are using the `unique_index` variable.

If you objective is to  get unique random list of questions then change you code to the followings:

```
public void QuestionChooser()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    public int qnum = r.Next(1, 25);


    if (!qList.Contains(qnum))
    {
        if (qnum == 1)
        {
            label1.Text = "Правилата за движение в населено място се прилагат:";
            button1.Text = "по всички участъци от пътя, по които се движат пешеходци";
            button2.Text = "след знака, с който е обозначено началото на населеното място";
            button3.Text = "от първата сграда в населеното място";
            button4.Text = "само, когато гледат полицаи";
            correctAns = 2;

            qList.Add(qnum);
            unique_index+= 1;
        }
        else if (qnum == 2)
        {

            label1.Text = "Когато светофара свети в жълто и червено значението е:";
            button1.Text = "Внимание, спри!";
            button2.Text = "Внимание";
            button3.Text = "Преминаването е забранено";
            button4.Text = "Преминаването е разрешено";
            correctAns = 3;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 3)
        {

            label1.Text = "Кой от изброените фактори е с най-голямо значение за определяне на дистанцията при движение зад друго ППС?";
            button1.Text = "марката на автомобила";
            button2.Text = "видът на превозвания товар";
            button3.Text = "състоянието на пътя";
            button4.Text = "видът на движещото се отпред ППС";
            correctAns = 3;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);
        }
        else if (qnum == 4)
        {

            label1.Text = "Когато няма други ограничения, водачите на леки моторни превозни средства с четири колела от категория 'АМ', при движение извън населено място, не трябва да превишават:";
            button1.Text = "45 км/ч";
            button2.Text = "50 км/ч";
            button3.Text = "40 км/ч";
            button4.Text = "55 км/ч";
            correctAns = 1;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 5)
        {

            label1.Text = "Как ще постъпите при заслепяване от светлините на насрещно движещо се превозно средство?";
            button1.Text = "ще сигнализирам със звуков сигнал";
            button2.Text = "ще го блъсна";
            button3.Text = "ще намаля скоростта";
            button4.Text = "ще продължа движението, като включа дългите светлини";
            correctAns = 3;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 6)
        {

            label1.Text = "На водача на МПС със специален режим на движение е забранено:";
            button1.Text = "да надвишава разрешената максимална скорост на движение";
            button2.Text = "да не спазва сигналите на регулировчика";
            button3.Text = "да преминава без да спира, при наличие на пътен знак, който изисква това";
            button4.Text = "да преминава при забраняващ сигнал на светофара";
            correctAns = 2;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 7)
        {

            label1.Text = "Конструктивната максимална скорост на мотопеда е не по-голяма от:";
            button1.Text = "50 км/ч";
            button2.Text = "55 км/ч";
            button3.Text = "60 км/ч";
            button4.Text = "45 км/ч";
            correctAns = 4;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 8)
        {

            label1.Text = "При движение на превозното средство в завой, с висока скорост, най-опасно е:";
            button1.Text = "ускореното износване на окачването";
            button2.Text = "ускореното износване на кормилната уредба";
            button3.Text = "ускореното износване на протектора на гумите";
            button4.Text = "възможното странично хлъзгане на автомобила";
            correctAns = 4;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 9)
        {

            label1.Text = "При изпреварването на кое от изброените ППС, трябва да се осигури по-голяма странична дистанция?";
            button1.Text = "автомобил";
            button2.Text = "велосипед";
            button3.Text = "съчленен автобус";
            button4.Text = "трактор";
            correctAns = 2;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 10)
        {

            label1.Text = "Какво влияние оказва върху дължината на спирачния път блокирането на колелата при спиране?";
            button1.Text = "намалява дължината на спирачния път";
            button2.Text = "не оказва влияние върху дължината на спирачния път";
            button3.Text = "увеличава дължината на спирачния път";
            button4.Text = "никакво";
            correctAns = 3;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 11)
        {

            label1.Text = "Когато паркирането върху тротоара е разрешено, разстоянието между превозното средство и сградата трябва да бъде не по-малко от:";
            button1.Text = " 1,0 м";
            button2.Text = " 2,0 м";
            button3.Text = " 0,5 м";
            button4.Text = " 1,5 м";
            correctAns = 2;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 12)
        {

            label1.Text = "На водача е разрешено да използва дългите светлини при:";
            button1.Text = "движение по осветени участъци от пътя";
            button2.Text = "разминаване";
            button3.Text = "движение зад друго МПС на разстояние, по-малко от 50 м";
            button4.Text = "намалена видимост";
            correctAns = 4;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 13)
        {

            label1.Text = "На водача на двуколесно превозно средство е разрешено:";
            button1.Text = "да се движи с включени светлини през деня";
            button2.Text = "да освобождава педалите, с които контролира превозното средство";
            button3.Text = "да управлява превозното средство, без да държи кормилото с ръка";
            button4.Text = "да превозва предмети, които пречат на управлението на превозното средство";
            correctAns = 1;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 14)
        {

            label1.Text = "Тротоарът е част от:";
            button1.Text = "платното за движение";
            button2.Text = "най-дясната пътна лента";
            button3.Text = "разделителната ивица";
            button4.Text = "пътното платно";
            correctAns = 4;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 15)
        {

            label1.Text = "Слизането на деца до 12 години от автомобил, спрял на пътното платно, се извършва от:";
            button1.Text = "страната на водача на МПС";
            button2.Text = "страната на пътния банкет";
            button3.Text = "не е разрешено";
            button4.Text = "от по-удобната на водача страна";
            correctAns = 2;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 16)
        {

            label1.Text = "Преди да намали значително скоростта на движение, водачът на МПС е задължен:";
            button1.Text = "да напусне платното за движение";
            button2.Text = "да премине в най-дясната пътна лента";
            button3.Text = "да сигнализира с десен пътепоказател";
            button4.Text = "да се убеди, че няма да застраши останалите участници в движението";
            correctAns = 4;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 17)
        {

            label1.Text = "Допълнителна задна светлина за мъгла е разрешено да се използва:";
            button1.Text = "само когато видимостта е намалена под 50 м";
            button2.Text = "при движение през нощта";
            button3.Text = "винаги при намалена видимост";
            button4.Text = "когато искате да покажете на задния каква кола карате";
            correctAns = 1;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 18)
        {

            label1.Text = "Разрешено ли е водачите на ППС да се движат в непосредствена близост зад превозните средства със специален режим на движение?";
            button1.Text = "да, когато няма ограничение на скоростта";
            button2.Text = "не";
            button3.Text = "да, във всички случаи";
            button4.Text = "да, но зависи от ситуацията";
            correctAns = 2;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 19)
        {

            label1.Text = "При несъответствие между сигналите на светофара и пътните знаци относно предимството трябва да се съобразявате:";
            button1.Text = "със светлинните сигнали";
            button2.Text = "с предписанията на пътните знаци";
            button3.Text = "който има по-силна музика";
            button4.Text = "който кара най-висока кола";
            correctAns = 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

            unique_index+= 1;

        }
        else if (qnum == 20)
        {

            label1.Text = "Има ли лекарства, след приемането на които е забранено управлението на МПС?";
            button1.Text = "да";
            button2.Text = "не";
            button3.Text = "да, но ако са наркотици";
            button4.Text = "да, но ако са с алкохол";
            correctAns = 1;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 21)
        {

            label1.Text = "Сигналът подаван от водача преди извършването на маневра осигурява ли му предимство?";
            button1.Text = "да";
            button2.Text = "не";
            button3.Text = "да, но ако завие рязко";
            button4.Text = "винаги, дори и да не дадат другите водачи път";
            correctAns = 2;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 22)
        {

            label1.Text = "При изпреварване се преминава от лявата страна на изпреварваното ППС.";
            button1.Text = "правилно";
            button2.Text = "грешно";
            button3.Text = "правилно, но ако първо надуя клаксона";
            button4.Text = "правилно, но ако първо присветна с дългите";
            correctAns = 1;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 23)
        {

            label1.Text = "Кои от изброените пътни превозни средства НЕ са моторни?";
            button1.Text = "трамваите";
            button2.Text = "мотопедите";
            button3.Text = "мотопедите";
            button4.Text = "автомобилите";
            correctAns = 1;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 24)
        {

            label1.Text = "Кое е грешното: преди да предприеме маневра водачът трябва да се убеди, че няма да създаде опасност за участниците в движението:";
            button1.Text = "които преминават покрай него";
            button2.Text = "които се движат след него";
            button3.Text = "които се движат пред него";
            button4.Text = "не е длъжен да се съобразява със сигналите, които подават";
            correctAns = 4;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 25)
        {

            label1.Text = "Зависи ли коефициентът на сцепление на автомобилните гуми с пътя от състоянието на пътната настилка?";
            button1.Text = "да";
            button2.Text = "не";
            button3.Text = "зависи";
            button4.Text = "ДРУГО";
            correctAns = 1;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);

        }
        else if (qnum == 26)
        {

            label1.Text = "Каква мярка се прилага към водач, който управлява моторно превозно средство без застраховка 'Гражданска отговорност' на автомобилистите - до предоставяне на сключена валидна застраховка?";
            button1.Text = "временно се отнема свидетелството за управление";
            button2.Text = "глоба";
            button3.Text = "прекратява се регистрацията на МПС";
            button4.Text = "предупреждение";
            correctAns = 1;

            unique_index+= 1;
            qList.Add(qnum);
        }
    }       
}
```

I am guessing you are calling the QuestionChooser() method in a while loop somewhere? Otherwise change the button5_Click to match the followings:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    unique_index = 0;
    while(unique_index < 26)
    {
        QuestionChooser();
    }
}
```